# Динамическое создание вложенных объектов в объектах Java Script

Tags: javascript, json, объекты

Есть страничка, на ней динамически создаются меню с input куда вводится название меню, в этих меню можно сгенерировать n-ое количество под меню с полем input у которых так же есть название(скрин прилепил внизу), и из всего этого нужно добывать инфу после нажатия на кнопку "сохранить настройки",т.е сколько создано меню, сколько в каждом меню-подменю и записывать все это в объект.
Вот что у меня получилось:

```
var i =0;
    $(`#Save__config`).click(function (e){
        //Идем по все минюшкам
        $.each($('.main_menu'), function (index, value) {
            //info.MainBlocks["MainBlock_" + index ]={};
            console.log(index + ':' + $(`#menuName-blockMenu-${index}`).val());
            //Идем по всем подменюшкам index минюшки
            $('input', $(`#containerMenu-blockMenu-${index}`)).each(function () {
              console.log(info.MainBlocks["MainBlock_" + index]={['SubMenu_MainBlock_'+i]:{}});
                i+=1;
                console.log($(this).val());
            });
            i=0;
        });
    });
```

Вот структура:

```
    info {
         MainBlocks: {
            MainBlock_number:  {  //допустим это созданная менюшка
               Name_Menu: "MenuName",//Имя менюшки введенное пользователем

               SubMenu_MainBlock_0: {//подменюшка 1
                   name_SubMenu: "SubMenuName",//естественно имя подменюшки
               }
               SubMenu_MainBlock_1: {//подменюшка 2
                   name_SubMenu: "SubMenuName",
               }
            }
         }
    }
```

Вот динамически создавать объекты самого меню я смог

```
//info.MainBlocks["MainBlock_" + index ]={};
```

Получается вот так, как надо!

```
info{
        MainBlocks: {
           MainBlock_1: {

           }
           MainBlock_2: {

           }
    },
}
```

Получается, что он считает все блоки и создает нужное количество объектов в объекте.
Но когда я хочу пройтись по всем подменюшкам менюшки, он делает вот это-
ставит поле со значением самой последний минюшки, т.е каждый раз перезаписывает поле.Пример на скрине

```
info{
        MainBlocks: {
           MainBlock_1: {
              SubMenu_MainBlock_2: {}
           }
           MainBlock_2: {
              SubMenu_MainBlock_1: {}
           }
    },
}
```

А надо вот так

```
info{
        MainBlocks: {
           MainBlock_1: {
              SubMenu_MainBlock_0: {},
              SubMenu_MainBlock_1: {},
              SubMenu_MainBlock_2: {},
           }
           MainBlock_2: {
              SubMenu_MainBlock_0: {},
              SubMenu_MainBlock_1: {}
           }
    },
}
```

Сама суть вопроса как правильно вот это оформить

```
info.MainBlocks["MainBlock_" + index]={['SubMenu_MainBlock_'+i]:{}}
```

что бы он не пересоздавал а добавлял постоянно новый.
Думал создал так просто объекты менюшки, так же просто и создам в них подменю, не вышло :))
Скрин [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного помучался и решил проблему, через добавление еще одного объекта и функции 
Object.assign( target, source );
[Может кому пригодиться](https://basicweb.ru/javascript/js_object_assign.php)

```
var i =0;
    $(`#Save__config`).click(function (e){
        $.each($('.main_menu'), function (index, value) {
           info.MainBlocks["MainBlock_" + index ]={};
           console.log(index + ':' + $(`#menuName-blockMenu-${index}`).val());
            $('input', $(`#containerMenu-blockMenu-${index}`)).each(function () {
                let str=$(this).val();
                let temp={}; //<------FIX
                temp["SubMenu_MainBlock_"+i]={}; //<------FIX

                Object.assign(info.MainBlocks["MainBlock_" + index],temp);// <------FIX

                i+=1;

                console.log($(this).val());

            });
            i=0;
        });
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]